# How can I make text adjust to the size of the screen in android?

Tags: android, screen-size, text-size

So far I have set up a page into grids which allows the page to adapt to screens of different sizes. 
I have been told to use different values files but I'd prefer not to. Is there a  way I can allow the text to naturally adapt to the screen size?

Comment: Us dp as unit. What do you expect from "adapt to screen size"?

Comment: Using values files is easy and the most effective way in my opinion. Otherwise text will be too large on phone or too small on tab.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sp` as the unit for your textSize property in the xml file or.

Here you can find a simple example:

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

or setTextSize at runtime:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28float%29

Answer (score 0):

You have to use sp or dp. These units are relative to the screensize.

Answer (score 0):

On TextView set `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` instead of wrap_content.
Then use `sp` in `android:TextSize`